# Uninstall system package cryptsetup

Tags: debian, uninstallation

I am usin Linux pine64 with 3.10.104-2-pine64-longsleep kernel. I want to remove a built in system package cryptsetup.
so far I have tried
`sudo apt-get remove cryptsetup`
`sudo apt-get remove cryptsetup-bin`
`sudo dpkg -r cryptsetup`
`sudo dpkg --purge cryptsetup`
The uninsallations were successful but somehow it it still running. when I execute
`sudo cryptsetup`
it still shows up.
Any pointers how do I remove it. I want to remove it and compile from source with openssl flags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y --purge remove cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin
```

Then reboot the computer and check if it succeeded.